# Chef: is there a way to compare the "status quo" to the "planned changes" and the "planned changes" to the "executed run"?

Tags: deployment, chef-infra, change-management

I would like to be able to extract the following information from Chef:

1. current state of the node vs. planned changes
2. panned changes vs state after the actual chef-client run

So far, I had the following idea:

1. compare `knife node show` && `chef-client -W`(log of why-run)

   - however, the output is in a different format (JSON vs log), I would have to parse the log and convert it into JSON (outch?)
2. compare `chef-client -W`(log of why-run) && `chef-client`(log):

   - here I could compare the two

What I want to achieve is some sort of change management visualized [here](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/view/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ3JhcGggTFJcblxuc3ViZ3JhcGggZGVwbG95bWVudCB3b3JrZmxvd1xuQVs8Y2VudGVyPiBmYTpmYS1sYXB0b3AgV29ya3N0YXRpb25dIC0tPnxwdXNoIDxici8-Y2hhbmdlcyB0b3wgQls8Y2VudGVyPiBmYTpmYS1naXRsYWIgR2l0bGFiIFJlcG9dXG5CIC0tPiB8R2l0bGFiIENJIDxici8-aW5pdGF0ZXN8IENbPGNlbnRlcj4gZmE6ZmEtZ2l0bGFiIEdpdGxhYiBSdW5uZXJdXG5CLS0-fGNvZGUgcmV2aWV3LDxici8-IG1lcmdlIHJlcXVlc3R8QlxuQy0tPnxzaW11bGF0ZSA8YnIvPmNoZWYtY2xpZW50IHJ1bnxDXG5DIC0tPnxwdXNoZXMgPGJyLz5jb29rYm9va3MgdG98IERbPGNlbnRlcj4gZmE6ZmEtc2VydmVyIENoZWYgU2VydmVyXVxuQy0tPnxpbml0aWF0ZXMgY2hlZiA8YnIvPnJ1biBvbnwgRVs8Y2VudGVyPiBmYTpmYS1jbG91ZCBDaGVmIENsaWVudF1cblxuc3ViZ3JhcGggQ2hlZiB3b3JrZmxvd1xuRS0tPnxwdWxscyA8YnIvPmNvb2tib29rcyBmcm9tfCBEXG5FLS0-fENoZWYgYXBwbGllcyA8YnIvPmNoYW5nZXN8IEZbPGNlbnRlcj4gZmE6ZmEtY2xvdWQgQ2hlZiBjbGllbnQgPGJyLz51cGRhdGVkXVxuRi0tPnxyZXBvcnRzIHN0YXR1cyA8YnIvPmJhY2sgdG98IERcbmVuZFxuXG5lbmRcblxuXG5HKCg8Y2VudGVyPkNoYW5nZSA8YnIvPm1hbmFnZW1lbnQpKVxuRy0tPnxnZXQgcGxhbm5lZCBjaGFuZ2VzIHxDXG5HLS0-fGdldCBub2RlIHN0YXR1cyBiZWZvcmUgY2hlZi1ydW58IERcbkctLT58Z2V0IG5vZGUgc3RhdHVzIGFmdGVyIGNoZWYtcnVufCBEXG5HLS0-fGNvbXBhcmUgPGJyLz4gYmVmb3JlLCA8YnIvPiBwbGFubmVkPGJyLz5hbmQgYWZ0ZXJ8IEciLCJtZXJtYWlkIjp7InRoZW1lIjoiZGVmYXVsdCJ9fQ)

In a form a trimmed down version of what Chef Automate seems to offer. I`m not sure if I'm actually shooting off my whole leg here. Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same hooks as Automate, write an event handler that records changes and sends them somewhere. https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#event-handlers

Comment: Thank you. How do I know which hooks Automate uses? Did I understand correctly that with the event handlers I can create "custom log files" which I can more easily compare (diff)?

Comment: It uses almost all of the event hooks, but the various `resource_*` ones are the most important, specifically the ones run after the resource converges successfully or otherwise.